# req.headers.split is not a function when getting token from header

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use the code sample from here https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js but my cloud function keeps crashing saying

```
req.headers.split is not a function
    at cors (/user_code/index.js:25:37)
    at cors (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
    at /user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
    at originCallback (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)
    at /user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
    at optionsCallback (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
    at corsMiddleware (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
    at exports.savedProfiles.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:14:5)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:41)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:671:7
```

I'm not sure how else to get it to work. This is the code that I've used so far:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

exports.savedProfiles = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        if ((!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.includes('Bearer '))) {
            console.log(req.headers);
            console.error('No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header.');

            res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
            return;
        }

        const tokenId = req.headers.split('Bearer ')[2];
        res.status(200).send('Testing');
        return;
    });
});
```

I understand that the error is due to `req.headers.split('Bearer ')[2];` which simply gets the token from the header. But I think the problem is that req.headers can be a `string` as well as a `string[]`. How would I go about getting this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`req.headers` is always an object indexed by the name of the header, never a string.  The code you referred to is doing this instead:

```
req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
```

It's accessing the "Authorization" header, which is a string, then splitting it.

Comment: so what is the correct way of doing this? Since this is what is written in the sample code

Comment: Your code is using `req.headers.split` instead of `req.headers.authorization.split`.